# A loop to check a value multiple rows with conditions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI4Gc.png)
I'm struggling with how to approach this problem.
What I have working:
I want to print all 3 rows in my table (Will attach example), and display the value in the EID column.

1. I want to test if the value of EID1 (first row) Starts with 8. (Done)
2. I want to test if the value of CID1 (first row) Starts with "M". (Done)
3. Now I want to loop the entire table and check the following conditions for each row, as an example:(Done)
4. If EID1 =< 8 and CID1 starts with M, print pass, else, print fail.
5. If EID2 =< 8 and CID2 starts with M, print pass, else, print fail.

I'm getting the following error: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of java.util.Map.get(object) is null.

I think this is probably because row (0) is actually null. I probably need to work out a way to skip the first iteration or there's an issue with my logic.

```
    query = "select * FROM PSA.SECOND where T_DATE >'2202-10-10'";
    
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query)
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
    long pId = 1:
    while (resultSet.next()) {
    for int col = 1; col <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); col ++) {
    result.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col)+pId, resultSet.getString(col)); }
    pId ++;
    }
    //print all results in col
    for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
    System.out.println("EID: "+result.get("EID"+i));

    //problem
    for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
    if (result.get("EID1").startsWith("8")){
    if result.get("CID1").startsWith("M") {
    System.out.println ("true");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. Do you notice a difference between the line where you print the value of the EID column, and the line where you check its value?

Comment: Hey. The output appears to be exactly what I would expect to see. I'm printing the values of EID and CID, specifically EID1 and CID1, their values on row one, which have the expected values (Correct values), now I just want to loop this condition to check EID1, EID2 and EID3 in a single loop with the same condition rather than write 3 seperate if statements. My issue is creating the loop, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: When you check the value you always use `1` as the suffix. You want to use `i`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just went over my head. At least that solves that part, but now I'm experiencing "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of java.util.Map.get(object) is null. I think this is probably because row (0) is actually null. I probably need to work out a way to skip the first iteration. If you have any pointers on that

Comment: You should update your question with the new code and an exact description of the new problem, including any stack trace.

Comment: Thanks again your advise. I've updated the error and code snip.

Comment: Please look at how you are generating the key for the map. You do not want a *literal* `i` as the suffix.

Comment: Hey. Not sure I follow that fully. Could you expand? I'm not that experienced.

Comment: You have the string `"EIDi"` as the key to your Map. What you want is `"EID1"`, then `"EID2"`, and so on, which you get from concatenating `"EID"` with the string representation of `i`, that is, `"EID"+i`, which is exactly what you do on the line where you print the value.

Comment: Yeah, I did have "EID1" and I was able to get it working with a simple if statement - the returned result was as expected. Quite basic. My issue is not wanting to use multiple if statements, each individually checking EID1, EID2 and EID3 in seperate statements and the condition. (And if/when I would add additional rows). I was looking to use a loop to check all the values with the condition in the code above. Creating that loop is my struggle. The above code just checks if EID1 meets the conditions 4 times. I want to check EID1, EDI2, EID3 in the same loop.

Comment: You have a loop which is already working: `for (int i=0; i<pId;i++) System.out.println("EID: "+result.get("EID"+i));`. You just need to use the same approach in your second loop.

Comment: That's why my struggle feels bad, because I just cannot seem to work it out, because when I provide EID+i I get the Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of java.util.Map.get(object) is null. I understand how to loop each value, but when I try to loop (under //problem) it fails with the above error. There's something wrong with it but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Update your question with your current code. The code in your question now is not using `"EID"+i`.

Comment: Alright. Under //problem is my current attempt to creating the loop with the following conditions. If I change the "i" to "1", it just loops row one 4 times and doesn't throw an error, because it's just checking EID on row 1, the same thing, 4 times. But I want to check row 2 and 3 (EID2 and EID3). I thought changing the EID1 to EID+i would work, but that throws the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
    System.out.println("EID: "+result.get("EID"+i));
```

Each key value takes the form `EID1`, `EID2` and so on.

In your second loop you do:

```
for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
    if (result.get("EID1").startsWith("8")){
        if result.get("CID1").startsWith("M") {
            System.out.println ("true");
        }
    }
```

You are using `EID1` every time.

You need to change your loop to:

```
for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
    if (result.get("EID" + i).startsWith("8")){
        if result.get("CID" + i).startsWith("M") {
            System.out.println ("true");
        }
    }
```

exactly as you are doing in your first loop.

Comment: Hey. My loop before my previous edit looked exactly the same. It makes sense this would work. But mine throws the following error when I use "i" over "1": Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" 
Because the return value of java.util.Map.get(object) is null. That's why I mentioned in the comments is this error being causing by my inexperienced  or do I need to skip the first first interation, if so, how?

I believe this is because iteration (0) is null, for example when I run my first loop to check all the values of EID, this is when turns:
EID - Null
EID - 800
EID - 500
EID - 800

Comment: Yes, you'll need to start at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

Comment: Hey. I did try this earlier but must've had some other issues trying to manage everything, but the solution does indeed work now and loops correctly. I initally tried looking at .skip(1) and others thing rather than such a simple solution due to my own error. I added the additional conditions and also working fine. Thanks a bunch man, really appreciate it. People like yourself keep everyone going.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using your database to do searching. So search for the failure criteria and then if there are no results, then print "true".

The below is a example based on some data assumptions that searches for your 'fail' criteria.

```
select 1
FROM PSA.SECOND
WHERE T_DATE >'2202-10-10'
    AND CID LIKE 'M%'
    AND EID <= 800
LIMIT 1
```

The advantage is that with indexing on `CID`,`EID` this can be a search that doesn't involve the entire dataset, and stops at the first failure.

Comment: I appreciate that would be ideal but I'm attempting to expand my knowledge primarily in automation testing and ultimately as I progress I'll want to check every value for a failure, not stop the test at the First failure.